# Non-unital algebras in geometric algebra, smooth envelopes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry

In Nestruev's (2000) *Smooth Manifolds and Observables*, the authors define an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra as a commutative, associative algebra with unit (p. 21). A natural generalization of this definition would drop the requirement of a unit. (For example, any self-adjoint, commutative, and non-unital C*-algebra defines such a "non-unital $\mathbb{R}$-algebra".) I am interested in how many of Nestruev's constructions carry over to the non-unital case. For example: is the notion of a smooth envelope of a geometric $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ well-defined if $\mathcal{F}$ lacks a unit?

*P.S. Apologies if this question is too preliminary; I am new to posting on this site. Many thanks for reading :)*

Comment: This is a pretty wide question. Without looking at the book, it looks like you are asking how much of a whole book can be reproduced by dropping an assumption. I suggest picking one single result you are interested in, asking about that.

Comment: What is the motivation behind such a question?  A nonunital R-algebra can be turned into a unital R-algebra using the unitization functor.  This reduces the study of nonunital algebras to unital algebras.  In geometric language, this corresponds to studying pointed spaces instead of spaces.

Comment: Very crudely speaking, one can argue that encoding a non-compact LCH space $X$ in terms of the non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra $C_0(X)$ is just the price you pay for working with an honest $C^\ast$-algebra of globally bounded functions without invoking any particular choice of compactification. Nestruev’s commutative-algebraic approach doesn’t require anything to be globally bounded, so the only non-unital algebras they ever need invoke are prime ideals of unital algebras.

Comment: David, thank you for the suggestion; I've edited the question to ask just about smooth envelopes. YCor, thanks for making the title more specific. Dimitri, my motivation is exactly the intuition that Branimir describes (i.e., that I want to work with an "honest" $C^*$-algebra of globally bounded functions like $C_0 (X)$, or a dense subspace of it containing only smooth functions).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: the existence of unitizations of Cstar algebras does not really reduce the non-unital theory to the unital theory, and indeed there are many instances where experience rather than categorical dictat indicates that one should work with the multiplier algebra not the unitization.

Comment: @YemonChoi: “Reduces” was used in the (narrow) context of OP's question, i.e., smooth envelopes of geometric R-algebras.  For C*-algebras, I recall a discussion here on MathOverflow about unitization, I am not sure whether any examples given there were convincing or not.

Answer (score 1):

> For example: is the notion of a smooth envelope of a geometric R-algebra F well-defined if F lacks a unit?

Yes.  Recall the construction: $F$ is *geometric* if the Gelfand homomorphism
$$\def\Map{\mathop{\rm Map}}
\def\Spec{\mathop{\rm Spec}}
\def\R{{\bf R}}
\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}}
G\colon F → \Map(\Spec(F),\R)$$
is injective, where $\Spec(F)=\Hom(F,\R)$ is the set of homomorphisms $F→\R$
and $\Map$ denotes the set of maps of sets $\Spec(F)→\R$.

The *smooth envelope* of $F$ is then constructed as
the real algebra $E$ generated by the image of $G$
inside $\Map(\Spec(F),\R)$
and closed under smooth compositions:
if $f_1,…,f_n∈E$ and $g\colon \R^n→\R$ is smooth,
then $g(f_1,…,f_n)∈E$.

What changes if $F$ is nonunital?
Homomorphisms $F→\R$ are defined in the same manner as before,
and in fact coincide with unital homomorphisms $\def\hF{{\hat F}} \hF→\R$,
where $F→\hF$ is the unitization of $F$.

The same definition of the Gelfand homomorphism continues to work.

The resulting smooth envelope is a unital algebra even if $F$ is not:
indeed, the unit is produced by taking $n=0$ and $g=1$ in the construction of the smooth envelope of $F$.
Even if we exclude $n=0$, we can always take $g=1$ for any $n$,
which still gives us the unit.